# Can a database have an unnamed row?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, table

I came across a question asking whether it is possible to have **unnamed** rows and columns in a database. I assumed **unnamed implied primary key.** I'm not sure whether my assumption is correct. When I searched it on the internet, I came across an [article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) with the following statement:

> The same row can appear more than once in an SQL table. The same tuple cannot appear more than once in a relation.

I thought that both **row**, **tuple**, and **record** mean the same thing.

What does this mean?

Comment: No idea what an unnamed row is, but a couple of differences between row, tuple and record.  A row is an element of a table in a physical database, a tuple is an element of a relation in relational database theory, and you can select three columns from two tables and get a number of records in return, as in a view or in a programming language.

Comment: Rows have no names. Columns always have names, and the column name is unique over a table. Index (key) is separate structure within the table, each index have a name which is also unique over the table. Primary key is an index with a lot of additional restrictions.

Comment: The phrase in Wiki means: 1) It is possible that the values of all columns in two different rows are the same; 2) It is not possible to have two separate rows in a table which produces equal expression values of the expressions which are used in the relation. Pay attention: "the same values" and "equal values" are different terms due to NULL existence.